# String matching doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby

I wrote this piece of code,

```
a="01. L-1-A-RA-REVENUE ACCOUNT"
b="01. L-1-A-RA-REVENUE ACCOUNT"
puts a.eql?b
```

This give me `false` while these strings are equal. Can anyone tell me what the problem is here?

Comment: hi, Chris, Your edit has changed my string, I don't know why, when I am taking it right now, it works fine, my string was this,a="01.    L-1-A-RA-REVENUE ACCOUNT"
b="01.    L-1-A-RA-REVENUE ACCOUNT"

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: To me, it seems like there might be some strange whitespace or control characters in the strings that are not rendered properly. See [this question on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283441/1639625).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [some research on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283441/1639625), it looks like the spaces in `a` are non-breaking spaces, while those in `b` are regular spaces. You can see this in the [source for revision one of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5a86d752-504f-4cc3-8ff7-5831565a37e0/view-source):

```
<pre style="width:650px; white-space:pre-wrap">hi I have written this small piece of code,

a=&quot;01.&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;L-1-A-RA-REVENUE ACCOUNT&quot;

b=&quot;01.    L-1-A-RA-REVENUE ACCOUNT&quot;

puts a.eql?b

This give me the result of false while these strings are absolutely equal, Can any one tell me what&#39;s the problem here? </pre>
```

Not really sure how this could happen; maybe you copied those strings from some HTML document?

Comment: hi, Thanks,I got the answer yesterday,Yes you are right, one string consist of right spaces, another one consist of non printable special character and it's ascii values if 160.

Comment: hi, I kept on telling people I do not know how to accept answer here, If you tell me, I would do it.

Comment: @RAJ Um, sure... you see that number at the top-left of the question? Below that number, there should be a grey checkmark icon. If you click that icon, it should turn green and the answer is accepted. Its also explained in the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

Try using `==`.

```
a="01. L-1-A-RA-REVENUE ACCOUNT"
b="01. L-1-A-RA-REVENUE ACCOUNT"
puts a == b
```

This returned true for me.

Comment: I used same result, Hi, when I am posting, the space in B got automatically removed, I don't know why. So I couldn't properly bring my string there.

Comment: @RAJ, I'm having some trouble understanding you. Does my code work for you?

Comment: So, do you say your val in b is same as a in your question..?

Comment: @Breenho yes b value is same as a, but it's not appearing

Comment: @Dbz hi,  b value is same as a while I am typing, but it's not appearing in the comment.

Comment: @RAJ I understand. Try using my code and tell me if it works. If it doesn't work, add these lines: `puts a` and `puts b`, and see if they're outputting the same thing.

Comment: @Raj, Please copy those two strings into some other editor and try to paste here from your editor. Also, check if string a has tabs between characters and b has spaces between characters. Or try to print a and b in console and paste here as DBZ suggested..

Comment: @Dbz the way you suggested doesn't work, it's printing the same, however I found the problem right now, I just used to a.each_byte, First string is printing 160 and second string is printing 32 in the place of space.

Comment: @Breenho I replied to Dbz what's the problem and I resolved now, please read the above comment of mine.